# MVC route for javascript logger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have problems to post back log entries from my MVC view to my server using jsnlog.js. It works fine from my "home/index" view when my site is accessed directly on the root url "\". In other views, when jsnlog.js tries to send data to url "jsnlog.logger" it seems that the url is changed into "customer/jsnlog.logger" where customer is the current controller name. 
This request ends up in a Http Status 404.

Can someone please give me an advise how to avoid the controller name to be inserted into the MVC route or if you have any other idea on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Probably your scripts generate a relative URL. Could you post the relevant parts?

Comment: Thanks, I think your assumption is correct. I just found this relative path inside jsnlog.js:  this.url = "jsnlog.logger";  Everything started to work when I inserted "/" in front of this path. I guess this is a bug inside the jsnlog library.

Comment: Same error - fixed by putting "./" in front of that path (@time of writing `this.url = "/jsnlog.logger";`)